# How to know which view can implement what listener

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

I would like to know, from where we can know about what listener a View can implement. For Ex. there is no meaning in implementing onItemSelectedListener in custom Edit Text view class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refer to the documentation ([View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), for example), there's a Nested Classes section that describes a list of interfaces that every `View` provides. For example, `View` class the `OnClickListener` interface, means every subclass of `View` would also provide it. And `AdapterView` (which is a parent of a `ListView`) provides the `OnItemSelectedListener`, means `ListView` will provide both `OnClickListener` and `OnItemSelectedListener`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the documentation, under the [Inherited Methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#inhmethods).